# Spring Boot @Formula displaying same likeCount on every result

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm having a problem with my @Formula field. I have three tables: user_acc, song and user_likes_song. I'm trying to display likeCount on songs based on how many times the songs ID appears in the many-to-many table.

My @Formula field in the Song entity looks like this:

```
@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(s.id) FROM user_acc u INNER JOIN user_likes_song us on u.id = us.user_id " +
            "INNER JOIN song s on us.song_id = s.id WHERE us.song_id = s.id )")
    private Long likeCount;
```

Currently when I like a song for the first time it shows "likeCount: 1" on every result. After I like another song it returns "likeCount: 2" on every result and so on.

Seems to me like it's counting all the likes in total, not for the specific song. How can I make it so it so it shows how many times a specific song ID appears in the many-to-many table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the match with every song rows :

```
INNER JOIN song s on us.song_id = s.id WHERE us.song_id = s.id
```

What you want is restricting it to the current song entity instance.
In fact, if the `@Formula` annotation is specified on a field of the `Song` entity, you don't want to specify `Song` in the query, instead you want to directly refer the field of the current entity (here `id`), that is :

```
WHERE us.song_id = id
```

So this should do the job :

```
@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_acc u INNER JOIN user_likes_song us on u.id = us.user_id " + "WHERE us.song_id = id )")
```

And I think that you could also simplify more in this way :

```
@Formula(" (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_likes_song us WHERE us.song_id = id) ")
```

because the join with user account doesn't matter.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! Using the query you provided I'm now getting this error: PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "s" :O

Comment: You are still welcome. I updated. I think that you can still simplify your query. Give it a go :)

Comment: Even better! You missed the parentheses around the query, but otherwise great!